# Azure DataFactory V2: Use SecureString Parameter in dynamic content

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a secure string parameter in data fatory

[image]

According to another post this is the way to access said parameter

```
@{pipeline().parameters.ChassisSqlUsername.value}
```

This use to and still give a validation error within the dynamic content window:
[image]

However the pipeline worked like this without issue. This validation error did not block publishing.

Asof today I can no longer publish if that validation error is present
[image]
[image]

**How do I get around this?**

Comment: Its not something daft like when its on its own it doesnt need the curly brace?

@pipeline().parameters.ChassisSqlUsername.value  curly brace is for embedding into other code and is it thinking theres a space or something there you're trying to embed it with

Comment: Curly braces or not gives the same error. And this exact pipeline worked and could be published 2 days ago. Wanted to make a change on a trigger today and failed. Think MS made an update that is more strict.

Answer (score 1):

Refer it in this way:

```
@{pipeline().parameters.ChassisSqlUsername}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the syntax of ADF is so terrible.

```
@{json(string(pipeline().parameters.ChassisSqlUsername)).value}
```